# Google Oauth for Refresh Token - invalid_grant

Tags: api, oauth, token, refresh, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to get a refresh token using PHP and curl from Google.  I have been following this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization#accessing_the_api)

The followed the instructions successfully to get the "code" that I need to eventually get my refresh token, so I know that is set up correctly and I am using a proper redirect uri.  Using the values that Google gives me to fill in my curl code, I created the following code:

```
$post = ["grant_type" => "authorization_code", "code" => "my recovered google code", "client_id" => "my oauth id", "client_secret" => "my client secret", "redirect_uri" => "my redirect id"];

$ch = curl_init('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// close the connection, release resources used
curl_close($ch);

// log my returned tokens
file_put_contents('./tokenLogger-'.date("H.i.s").'.log', $result, FILE_APPEND);
```

All that I am getting my my log file is this:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```

I have wasted two days and could really use some direction.  I am following Google's directions, and yet it is failing for me.  Any insight would be extemely helpful.  Thank you!!

Comment: The problem is most likely your `redirect_uri` value. However, when you requested `code` you needed to request `access_type=offline`. When asking for help include everything except for secrets. The answer is in what you left out. Here is an article that I wrote on how to use the CLI curl to do Oauth 2.0. Maybe this will help you: https://www.jhanley.com/google-oauth-2-0-testing-with-curl-version-2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one was frustrating, but turned out to be fairly straight forward.  When trying to obtain a refresh token, you must get a "code" from google that you use to obtain the refresh token.  This "code" is only good for **one use!**  If you try to use it and you have a bug in your code, you must generate a new "code" before you can try again.  Whether it succeeds or fails, you only get one shot.  I was under the impression that I could keep using it until it succeeded.  That is not correct.